# Are there any known builtin functions or libraries to get quotation mark characters for a language?

Tags: internationalization

Different languages use different glyphs for quotation marks ([See this Wikipedia page for more detailed information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks)). Are there functions built-in to any or all of the most popular tablet operating systems out there (Windows Store Apps, Android, iOS) to get the appropriate left and right quotation marks for a given language? If so please point me to the docs. Using a builtin API would be a much better solution than reinventing the wheel and creating my own lookup table matching language to quotation mark characters. Alternatively if there is an open source library with this lookup table that would a second best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Sort of.

For Java you can use [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/), namely [LocaleData class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html). You'll get normal and alternative quotes.

Unfortunately, they haven't ported this class to C, so this information might be a bit useless for you. That is, unless you know a thing or two about [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository aka CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) and the things it provides (this is usually the source of information for ICU).
There is [certain element in LDML](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-general.html#Ellipsis) that contains what you are looking for. For example, you may find quotation marks for French language (in JSON format) by [visiting this link](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-aux/json/23.1/main/fr/delimiters.json).

CLDR is a bit hard to navigate, but you can create what you need on your own.

As for OS data, I don't really think that this is available, I am unaware of availability of quotation marks...